# finding data in MySQL using multidimensional array data

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to search this, but I keep finding solutions to problems "MySQL to Multi-dimensional arrays"

I have a multidimensional array, and I'd like to use values from the array to search through my MySQL database and output whatever I need to.

Do I use `WHERE` clause? `IN` clause? I'm in need of some help

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 333
            [name] => Watches
            [pluralName] => Watches
            [shortName] => Watches
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [id] => 111
            [name] => Bar
            [pluralName] => Bars
            [shortName] => Bar
        )

)
```

If I have some syntax like this:

```
$categorySet = $dbh->prepare("SELECT c.*,ci.*,b.business_id,b.idbusiness FROM
categories c 
JOIN categories_items ci ON ci.idcategory = c.idcategory
JOIN businesses b ON b.idbusiness = ci.id_items
WHERE c.id = :id OR c.name LIKE :name");
$categorySet -> bindParam(:name, $array['id']);
$categorySet -> bindParam(:name, '%'.$array['name'].'%');
$categorySet -> execute();
```

I'd like to search through MySQL but would like to get outputs with watches OR bars from the array.

Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check conditions you always needed `WHERE` clause so you must need it.

Second `IN` clause allow to use array when array is in `array(1,2,3,4,5);` form.

**IN example**

```
SELECT
 *
FROM table_name 
WHERE
  fields IN (array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

**More Information**

```
$id_sql = array();
$name_sql = array();

foreach($conditionArray as $arry)
{
       $name_sql[] = $arry['name'];
       $id_sql[]    = $arry['id'];
}

$ids    = implode(',',$id_sql);
$names  = implode(',',$name_sql);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ($ids) AND name IN ($names)
```

If you can then please make separate array for names and ids so you don't need to use `for-each` just `implode` it and send it in `MySQL` statement.

Comment: does that mean I have to change my array format? Also, what does fields consist of? do I write it as like `id,name IN (array(1,2,3,4,5))`?

Comment: @andrewliu no no no bro...you need to create array for each of name and id then use AND clause...and i gave example for fields it can be whatever type.

Comment: Oh i see, well I dont think I want to use AND clause, I'd like to use OR. So it should look like this? `WHERE name IN (array(name1,name2,etc...)) OR id IN (array(id1,id2,etc...));`

Comment: @andrewliu see updated answer...yah whatever you like you can use AND and OR

Comment: @andrewliu by the way IN clause already perform OR condition it will check for id in passed array inside id IN condition.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot! I think this definitely helps and is what I'm looking for!

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$arr_queries = array ('values','values','values')
$arr_results = array();

foreach($arr as $values)
{
  $sql = //do sql query here using $values,
  if(mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0)
  {
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
         $temp = array();
         $temp[] = $row[0]// get first column value, add other column value on $temp array
     } 
  }

  $arr_results[] = $temp;
}

?>
```

Comment: $arr_results will get have all the returned value on your sql query

Comment: hey dude he is asking for query not how to display it... be careful

Comment: In addition to not addressing the query, you have array_ queries serving no purpose whatsoever